# Python code error. defining the character of the first word

Tags: python-3.x

If the first letter of `ln` is 'a', I would like to print but python is telling to define 'a'. how do it define a as the first letter.

## My code

```
print("Enter first name")
fn = input("name\t")
print("Enter last name")
ln = input("name\t")
print("Enter month of birth eg. Jan-1")
num = int(input("no\t"))
print('\n')
print('first name is %s, last name is %s, month of birth is %d' %(fn,ln,num)) 
if(fn[0] == chr(a)):
    print('First letter is a')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just define a string literal:

```
if fn[0] == 'a':
```

Comment: Thanks Martijn. Am just a starter and am trying to do a simple program. might need your help completing it

Answer (score 1):

From the Python docs

> ### chr(i)
>
> Return the string representing a character whose Unicode code point is the integer i

Hence, `char(97)` would return 'a'.

As stated previously, using a string of 'a' would be more efficient in your example.

`if fn[0] == 'a':`